# FCM access token key via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-cloud-messaging

Is there any option to get the FCM access token key via Java Script on the client side?
I'm using Firebase for a simple android app' and I want to let some users the option to send a push notification messages.

```html
function getAccessToken(){  }

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.responseType = "json";
xhr.open('POST', "https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/**********/messages:send", true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', "Bearer " + getAccessToken());
```

I tried the suggestion of @Ali with the following code snippet but now I'm getting an exception from refreshAccessToken(...) with the message of "Scopes not configured for service account.".
I want to clarify that the DotNet code from the first comment of Ali's answer is still working with the same JSON file.

```html
@JavascriptInterface
private static String readToken() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    String str = new String("{\n" +
            "  \"type\": \"service_account\",\n" +
            "  \"project_id\": \"*****\",\n" +
            "  \"private_key_id\": \"*****\",\n" +
            "  \"private_key\": \"-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\\n*****\\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\\n\",\n" +
            "  \"client_email\": \"*****\",\n" +
            "  \"client_id\": \"*****\",\n" +
            "  \"auth_uri\": \"*****",\n" +
            "  \"token_uri\": \"*****",\n" +
            "  \"auth_provider_x509_cert_url\": \"*****",\n" +
            "  \"client_x509_cert_url\": \"*****\"\n" + "}\n");

    InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(str.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    GoogleCredentials googleCredential = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(stream);
    googleCredential.createScoped(Arrays.asList("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.messaging"));

    AccessToken token = googleCredential.refreshAccessToken();
    String x = token.getTokenValue();
    return x;
}
```

Comment: Do you have a webView in your app which want to use JavaScript in it?

Comment: Yes, I'm using WebView component to view the HTML content and I also enabled JavaScript.

Comment: Try this: `googleCredentials.getApplicationDefault().createScoped(....blah)`

Comment: It didn't help. App was crashed with the following callstack: 06-13 22:33:34.878 30601-30601/com.my.app E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.my.app, PID: 30601
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.my.app/com.my.app.MainActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3003)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3064)
   ...

Comment: Sorry I have no more Idea except that if the user should be online to work with applications, you can implement the working `.net` page  on your own server and send an Ajax request to the `.net` page and get the result.

Comment: It worked for me when I moved it from the main thread. Thank you @Ali

Comment: I am glad that this question is finally solved. Please clarify if `getApplicationDefault()` was necessary so I add it to the accepted answer.

Comment: No it wasn't necessary...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After creating a webview, enable JavaScript and also attach a JavaScript interface and name it something:

```
WebSettings webSettings = webview.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webview.addJavascriptInterface(this, "InterfaceName");
```

Now you can assign any Java function into the JavaScript interface and access it through the Web Pages.

Sample for getting user FCM token:

```
@JavascriptInterface
public String readToken(){
    String token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
    return token;
}
```

Sample for getting FCM access token key ([reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/auth-server)):

```
@JavascriptInterface
private static String readToken() throws IOException {
  GoogleCredential googleCredential = GoogleCredential
      .fromStream(new FileInputStream("service-account.json"))
      .createScoped(Arrays.asList(SCOPES));
  googleCredential.refreshToken();
  return googleCredential.getAccessToken();
}
```

To add the access token to an HTTP request header :

```
URL url = new URL(BASE_URL + FCM_SEND_ENDPOINT);
HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + getAccessToken());
httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; UTF-8");
return httpURLConnection;
```

and this is how you can call that function using JavaScript inside the WebView which you have defined the interface:

```
<script>
   var token=InterfaceName.readToken();
</scritp>
```

Comment: Thank you Ali, it looks like a good point to start with but it seems that this token is not the token that I need. The following DotNet code do the job: using (var stream = new FileStream("project-firebase-adminsdk.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    var credential = GoogleCredential.FromStream(stream).CreateScoped("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.messaging", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform");
    var token = credential.UnderlyingCredential.GetAccessTokenForRequestAsync().Result;
} // How can I do it on Java?

Comment: Is this code being run on a server or on the client device? If this is a server code, you can access the output of this DotNet page using an Ajax call. @Itay

Comment: This code should be run on the client side. I want to know how to convert it to JavaScript or Android Java.

Comment: I have updated the answer with more samples from FCM documentation. Please check. @Itay

Comment: I tried your suggestion and I still haven't managed to get the token key. I have updated my question with more details. please advice @Ali